# how can I limit my div with draggable in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

i use a long  gray pane which can be draggable and i have a window to over the pane.
the window is overflow:hidden; on the pane. 
then how can I drag the pane without the white part and the pane can bounce if it can't be drag?
the effect i want is like the timeline bar in following web:

http://world.time.com/2013/12/05/nelson-mandelas-extraordinary-life-an-interactive-timeline/

(when i drag too many left or right, it will bounce itself. so the white part won't appear)

thank u :)

PS. i try to use the draggable but i don't know how to do this~

HTML

```
`<div class="window" style="width:1000px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;">
     <div class="pane" style="background:grey;width:4000px;height:200px"></div>
 </div>            `
```

JS

```
JS
`$('.pane').draggable({

     axis:x;
});
`
```

Comment: Check jQuery++ at jquerypp.com. It covers your requirement and give extra power to drag and drop.

Comment: thank you for your advice. i try the jQuery++, but the drag.limit() method can't respond my need. because my pane is longer than its parent. still thanks and i will try another methods in jQuery++.

Comment: What do you mean *" I have a window to over the pane"*..?

Comment: I use a div which class is window and another div which class is pane. 
<div class="window"><div class="pane"></div></div>
the pane's width is long but the window use overflow:hidden to hide the part it out of the window